# Count entries per row in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with a row per customer and columns that are attributes about that customer. I want to know for each customer how many attributes are populated...i.e. not null values.

As an example I have this:

[image]

And I want my output to be this:

[image]

What would be the sql for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select customer,
       (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end
       ) as num_entries
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping not to go down this route as there are 500 columns in the table.

Comment: @BrettRinehold . . . (1) You'll need to reference all the columns for whatever solution you choose.  (2) You can generate the code using a spreadsheet or SQL query.  (3) That situation suggests a flaw in the data model, suggesting that you want the values in separate rows.

Comment: I'd be very hesitant to switch to what would probably an entity attribute value model. Yes, it might simplify this specific query, but the issues with eav models are well documented.